# Can continuity of real functions be "globally" characterized?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Most characterizations of pointwise continuous functions defined on an interval rely on "local" properties. That is, a function is continuous at $x_0 \in I$ if it satisfies some property (epsilon-delta, sequential, oscillation, etc); a function is continuous on an interval if it is continuous at all $x \in I$.

> Is there a characterization of pointwise continuous functions $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ which relies solely on "global" properties of the function?

An example (but, of course, incorrect, in this case) of a "global" property would be the intermediate value property.

Comment: Is "inverse images of open sets are open" a global definition?

Comment: @coffeemath I haven't studied topology yet so I'm not totally sure...if you feel it is, though, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: MathematicsStudent1122 I would put that answer up provided you were familiar with open sets and inverse images of functions. But maybe you could mention in your question just what global properties you already know about.

Comment: @coffeemath I know what inverse images are from set theory. I think that answer is fine so long as you don't get too abstract (ex. replace "open sets" with "open intervals" if that's possible). An exhaustive list of what I do and do not know is difficult...

Comment: MathematicsStudent1122 Yes I thought of that later that a list of that would be too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to mention that "open sets" may be replaced by "open intervals" in the definition I mentioned (and which Renan R. cites in his answer).

Simply put an open set $O$ is one for which given any $x\in O$ there is an open interval $I$ for which $x \in I \subseteq O.$ So if inverse images $f^{-1}(I)$ are each open for any $I,$ then by taking unions of intervals we get to the more "abstract" version that inverse images of open sets are open. Conversely, since open intervals are a special type of open set, we can go the other way.

*Note:* It is *not* the case that the inverse image of an open interval has to be a single open interval. Consider $f(x)=x^3-100x$ and the inverse image of the interval $(-1,1)$ under $f.$ This will consist of three disjoint open intervals, one near each of $0,10,-10.$ And there are likely other examples where the inverse image of a single interval can be more complicated than that, perhaps have infinitely many components, or even an arbitrary open set (I don't have examples for either of these situations).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Definition:** $f$ is said to be continuous when pre-image of open sets are open sets, that is, if $A$ is open then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.